# Stats Model Power Calculation

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

The documentation is not very clear about the method for computing the number of samples estimated for a significant result, precisely the number of N. For example, does this N relate to one distribution? So, is the output the total number of observations (across both distributions in an A/B test), or is it just one? I've seen conflicting uses; the documentation doesn't specify precisely what it outputs.

```
statsmodels.stats.power.tt_ind_solve_power(effect_size=None, nobs1=None, 
alpha=None, power=None, ratio=1.0, alternative='two-sided')
```

Available from the following link
https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.power.tt_ind_solve_power.html

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit? Are you just trying to understand the output? If i understand your question correctly, since you have ratio set to 1.0, which is the ratio of group B n to group A n, you have identical n. So based on the other parameters it'll give you an N to obtain a reliably significant result for both groups.

Comment: The variable solved for is `nobs1=None`, so it's the sample size of the first sample. The second sample size nobs2 is defined through nobs1 and ratio. Definitions in docstring look pretty clear to me. (however, docs have very few examples)